# DotNet HighCharts Png Image

Tags: javascript, image, highcharts

I added a new button in exporting list of a chart

```
Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems.push({
                text: 'Add Issue ',
                onclick: function () {
                    this.AddIssue();
                }
            });
```

i want to add a screenshot of a chart in the img tag in same page when i click AddIssue button,

```
Highcharts.Chart.prototype.AddIssue = function () {
 ....
 $('#mock').attr('src', .........);
}
```

i had an img tag as

```
<img id="mock" src="../" />
```

i tried using **getSVG** Function but i want it to be a **PNG** or **JPEG** image not SVG.

Inside AddIssue Function

```
 var svg = this.getSVG();                 
 var base_image = new Image();
 var Isvg = "data:image/svg+xml," + svg;
 base_image.src = Isvg;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert SVG from getSVG method to PNG by HTML canvas:

```
  load: function() {
    var chart = this,
      svg;

    $('#btn').on('click', function() {
      svg = chart.getSVG();

      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = chart.chartWidth;
      canvas.height = chart.chartHeight;

      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var img = document.createElement('img');

      img.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      };

      img.setAttribute('src', 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(svg))));
    });
  }
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3azfr1nL/

Other solutions can be find here: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/15/3-ways-to-export-highcharts-charts-to-image-with-javascript-client-side-solution-

and here: https://gist.github.com/philfreo/0a4d899de4257e08a000

Comment: Hi Can you please say where this png is saved.I want to save png in my server side

Comment: @user2513019 the official documentation how to set your own export server you can find here: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server